# It is possible to import new property, functionality and html from other file to exists component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the package with free and pro components.

I need to add new functionality (pro) for exists free component.

For example, I have a free component

```
import React from "react";

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clickCounter: 0
    }
  }

  addClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      clickCounter: this.state.clickCounter+1
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <button onClick={this.addClick}>Click {this.state.clickCounter}</button>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

and in folder `component/pro/` I want new functionality. (This folder is being deleted for the free package build)

And I would like the same component to have more possibilities under the same name for the pro version only.

For example, the limit of clicks.

What is the best way to do it?

Should I remove excess code from the component, or somehow can I load additional functions into an existing component.

Comment: What is going on? If it is not an open-source project why you can't add it to your build? The code will be visible anyway, you can just restrict its use

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you are distinguishing between a free and a Pro user, and based upon that you want to serve the respective features.

Your user details API should tell you about the user status, (Free or PRO). Based upon that response you can implement like below.

```
import FreeExample from './FreeExample';
import ProExample from './ProExample';
import AppLoader from './AppLoader';


class App extends React.Component {
  isProUser = ({ userData }) => userData.status === 'PRO';

  render() {
     const { userData, isLoading } = this.props;
     if(isLoading) return <AppLoader />
     return (
       { isProUser({ userData })  ? <ProExample /> : <FreeExample />}
     );
 }
}
```

Comment: I have two packages file to import components. 
In package.json dependency

`"package": "./package.zip"` or `"package": "./packagePro.zip"`.

then I can import my component `import {Button} form 'myPackage'`

And package-pro.zip has a folder with pro components. The folder `pro` is being deleted for the free package build. I was wondering if it is possible to import additional functions from the pro folder for the free component. 

And then I remove folder `pro` from my package and build (free) everything should work correctly without functionality, props etc from `pro` folder

Comment: This could be a part of the build job, at the time of build your Pro package is getting removed. It would be helpful to look at the build code. If possible please share the webpack build code.

Comment: The compilation is done by running the script to delete the pro folder (and others files and code for imports pro components). The only thing I can say is that I can use regex is to review the file and remove the excess code, but I expected it might be an easier way.

Comment: There are multiple ways you can do this. A couple of them on top of my mind are.
1 ) Update the deleting script to not deleted the entire Pro folder but only delete the subfolders, which could be passes as a argument.

2) Create a separate package, call it commonFreeAndPro. and ignore this from the build job.